# UWP- Navigation cache and properties not changing during navigation?

Tags: c#, caching, navigation, win-universal-app

I'm building a UWP app and the navigation works like this- You start at Page1 which has a list of navigation options. Page1 creates a viewmodel object will some identifying parameter set, and passes it to Page2 which overrides OnNavigatedTo to set the viewmodel to one of its properties and calls an internal method to populate the viewmodel's data.

When navigating to a page the first time, all of this works. The viewmodel is passed in, data is set, and everything is displayed correctly. However when I navigate to page 1 then page to page 2 with a different parameter, it seems as though internally the viewmodel changes, but the display does not accurately reflect these changes. The viewmodel and its properties DO correctly implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

We figured out that Page2 had NavigationCacheMode set to Enabled. When we disabled the navigation cache, the page changed as expected. Based on this, it seems as though when we change the data in the OnNavigatedTo method, our changes end up getting overridden by the data pulled from the cache? Is this correct, and if so is there somewhere else we should be populating our viewmodel to avoid this? Or should we simply check if the page's parameters have changed and conditionally clear the cache to force a full reload?